# One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK'

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to mount the value of variable $SSH_AUTH_SOCK inside a docker container on a host using ansible. I'm using shell module of ansible.

```
shell: >
docker run -d
--name ****
-p ****:***
-h ****:****
-v {{ ansible_env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}:/ssh_auth.sock
<image name> /bin/bash /root/abc.sh
```

But its throwing the error

> One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK'

I tried to debug this by extracting the json of setup module using ansible -i inventory -m setup localhost and trying to print the variable using

> debug module  debug: msg="System has uuid {{ ansible_env.AUTH_SOCK }}"

and it shows the same error.

> One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute
>   'SSH_AUTH_SOCK'

I'm attaching the json snippet below:

```
"ansible_env": {
            "HOME": "/home/vagrant",
            "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8",
            "LC_CTYPE": "en_US.UTF-8",
            "LESSCLOSE": "/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s",
            "LESSOPEN": "| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s",
            "LOGNAME": "vagrant",
            "LS_COLORS": "*****",
            "MAIL": "/var/mail/vagrant",
            "OLDPWD": "*****",
            "PATH": "****",
            "PWD": "/home/vagrant/deploy/vagrant/ansible",
            "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
            "SHLVL": "1",
            "SSH_AUTH_SOCK": "/tmp/ssh-syce2sxVuO/agent.17243",
            "SSH_CLIENT": "10.0.2.2 53762 22",
            "SSH_CONNECTION": "10.0.2.2 53762 10.0.2.15 22",
            "SSH_TTY": "/dev/pts/0",
            "TERM": "xterm",
            "USER": "vagrant",
            "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR": "/run/user/1000",
            "XDG_SESSION_ID": "5",
            "_": "/usr/local/bin/ansible"
        },
```

I'm able to access the values from **ansible_env.HOME** to  **ansible_env.SHLVL** but the values from **ansible_env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK** to
**ansible_env.SSH_TTY** are not accessible and is throwing error

> One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute
>   .

Any ideas ?